# Disallowing reference captures in a std::function?

Tags: c++

In my program I have a job queue. Jobs are specified via a `std::function`.

```
void queueJob(std::function<void()> lambda);
```

Jobs are added to the queue and then executed later. (This is all dramatically simplified for purposes of making the question clear.)

Because the lambdas are executed outside the stack frame of `queueJob()`'s caller, reference captures to the lambda are always wrong.

```
{
    LocalObject o;
    queueJob([&]() { print(o); }); // wrong
    queueJob([o]() { print(o); }); // right
}
```

In order to prevent problems, it'd be really useful if there was a way to specify in `queueJob()`'s type signature that the `std::function` parameters it takes *may not contain reference captures*.

Can this be done?

Comment: This is not allowed, and for a good reason: `queueJob()` can only see as far as data hiding allows. The captures are the lambda's own territory, no external object has anything to do with it. Also, it'd be conceptually wrong: you could capture e.g. globals or fn arguments. Reference captures are not wrong, they can be used carefully and effectively.

Comment: C++ has no life-time in its type, contrary to Rust. They might have some borrow checker tools for C++...

Comment: Nope, this cannot be done in C++.

Comment: Before trying to control what a lambda may capture, how do you know that there is a lambda? Do you have a way to enforce that the `std::function` does in fact come from a lambda instead of, say, a pointer to a (nullary) function?

Comment: @JaMiT +1, or any other functor.

Comment: @JaMiT Good point --- _do_ I have such a way?